# Why current gain of common emitter transistor changes with the change of transistor

Tags: transistors

I was reading a book on basic electronic engineering and there it said that if we replace a transistor with a new one and even if we keep all other parameters same for both transistors then also the current gain is likely to change.

But I couldn't justify why should gain change if we keep all parameters same. Thanx

Comment: Because the new transistor is not likely to have all parameters the same as the old one.

Comment: @ThePhoton OP's post says the parameters are all the same however. I am thinking there may be some misinterpretation because it is unlikely the transistors have the same parameters as you stated.

Comment: The current gain will likely be different if you have a different transistor.  Therefore the parameters are probably not the same.  I think this question should be closed due to unclarity.

Comment: Probably the question means the external parameters are the same (e.g. bias).

Comment: its clear enough. All parameters *other than the transistor* are kept the same in the circuit. @ThePhoton and Ken Shirriff agree (and so do I).

Comment: I do mean that all external parameters are same .

Comment: The book is probably trying to convey that designs should account for component tolerances, particularly transistors (but not limited to).

Comment: Just read chapters 2 and 3 in the Art of Electronics, some transistors are more "the same" than others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gain depends on manufacturing characteristics such as the thickness of the base and the doping level. These won't be exactly the same from one batch to another (or even one transistor to another), so the gain will vary.